# COM dll is not being flushed out

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke, dllimport

I am interacting with a custom COM component called CSCCOM in my c# project.

I am wrapping it with IDisposable as below:

***Form1.cs***

```
try {
    using (CSCCOMWRAP CSC = new CSCCOMWRAP()) {
        CSCCodeList CSCL = new CSCCodeList(CSC);

        comboBox1.DataSource = CSCL.List;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CSCL);
    }
}
catch (COMException ex) { }
```

***CSCCodeList.cs***

```
try {
    var cscl = CSC.GetCodes();

    for (int i = 1; i <= cscl.Count(); i++) {
        object item = i;
        var code = cscl.Item(ref item);

        List.Add(new CSCCode((string)code.Name, Convert.ToString(code.Code)));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { );
```

Once the program is executed, I still see CSCCOM.dll ***twice*** in the [ProcessExplorer's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) lower pane's DLL view.

This suggests that for some reason my COM dll is not getting flushed out of the system.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you deleted this question? Normally only useless questions are deleted, and this question clearly isn't useless.

Comment: Thank you @mmyers. Please, what's your first name?

Comment: @mmyers: I agree. But I thought I was over exposing my code. But I feel I should have edited it than deleting it. Appreciate your critique on this action of mine :) I really do apologize to MrDosu for this.

Comment: Since this is an old question, some feedback for you - hope it is helpful, Moon! I notice that your questions are quite chatty, and they can sometimes be simplified quite a bit by making them more succinct. This saves the time of readers (less stuff to read) and editors (less chat to trim).

Comment: All of the following can be removed, generally speaking: thanks, thanks in advance, regards, sig blocks, stating that you need help, hopes that people can help, urging people to help, stating that help would be nice, worries that the question is too simple, stating that you don't understand the problem, etc. They are all either obvious or unnecessary. Short and sweet is good here `:-)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time no COM, but it seems to me you are never releasing the cscl or code vars in

```
                var cscl = CSC.GetCodes();

                for (int i = 1; i <= cscl.Count(); i++) {
                    object item = i;
                    var code = cscl.Item(ref item);

                    List.Add(new CSCCode((string)code.Name, Convert.ToString(code.Code)));
```

with ReleaseComObject, resulting in RCW counts not being decremented and making the dll "float around"

Comment: How did I missed that? Thanks a lot for pointing it out :) Really appreciate it :)

Comment: because COM is sadistic black magic created to torture the progging kind ;p

Answer (score 0):

Here is what needed to be modified in `CSCCodeList.cs`:

```
try {
    var cscl = CSC.GetCodes();

    for (int i = 1; i <= cscl.Count(); i++) {
        object item = i;
        var code = cscl.Item(ref item);

        List.Add(new CSCCode((string)code.Name, Convert.ToString(code.Code)));

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(code);
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cscl);
}
```